# jQuery UI autocomplete- no results message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to have a "No Results" message appear in the dropdown menu if there are no results.  So for instance, if I type in "ABCD" into the text field, and there is no entity that matches, the message "No Results." will be displayed.

After looking through stackoverflow for the various different ways of accomplishing this, and trying a few of them, I still can't get it to work.

How can I add a "No Results" message to the dropdown menu when no results are found?

**jQuery:**

```
    $element.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {            
            $.ajax({
                url: thUrl + thQS,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        if (data.indexOf(item) === -1) {
                            return { label: "No Results." }
                        } else {
                            return {
                                label: item.Company + " (" + item.Symbol + ")",
                                value: item.Company
                            }
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: that.options.minLength,
        select: function (event, ui) {
               reRenderGrid();
        }
    });
```

I have tried adding an if() statement with the following but that didn't work.

```
if (data.length === 0) {
    // Do logic for empty result.
}
```

I am able to overwrite the first entry with the text "No Result" if I do the following...

```
if (data.indexOf(item) === 0) {
    return { 
        label: "No Results." 
}
```

...but if I set `data.indexOf(item) === -1` nothing shows up.

I just recently tried the following, and when there is no data, it goes into the loop, however, "No Results" is not being displayed in the menu:

```
   success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.Company + " (" + item.Symbol + ")",
                value: item.Company
            }
        }));
        if (data.length === 0) {
            label: "No Results."
        }
    }
```

I have also attempted to use the below example from Andrew Whitaker with no luck:

ANDREW WHITACKER'S FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/128/

SOURCE: http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/2012/10/08/jqueryui-autocomplete-1-9/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
if (!ui.content.length) {
    var noResult = { value:"",label:"No results found" };
    ui.content.push(noResult);
    //$("#message").text("No results found");
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/129/

**Update**

Put the code at the end of your auto-complete setup just after `select: function (event, ui) {..}`

```
    ..........
    minLength: that.options.minLength,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        reRenderGrid();
    },   //HERE - make sure to add the comma after your select
    response: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {
            var noResult = { value:"",label:"No results found" };
            ui.content.push(noResult);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Trevor.  I noticed you edited Andrew Whitacker's fiddle, however, his fiddle isn't exactly the same as mine.  Where would I put your above code?  Somewhere around my select statement?  Can you create a fiddle using just my code?

Comment: Hey Trevor.  I tried it, but it didn't work.  I can't help but think it's because I already have a response.  So if the first response in the success statement is successful, will it also execute the second one below the select statement?  In my case, it didn't even reach the statement.  I put a breakpoint in and it never stopped.

Comment: @Keven Well I don't know what to tell you unless you can get an working example fiddle with your code..  Its not the `other response` Here is one more fiddle that is a lot like my first fiddle except for the way I setup the ajax success function looks like yours.  http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/130/  Try to get your code as close to the fiddle format as you can.

Comment: Does using "response" require a particular version of JQuery? I can't get this to work in 1.8.17 - the response code never gets hit, but there are no JS errors.

Comment: @NickG I don't believe so, I tested it using my fiddle on JQuery 1.7.2 and the "response" ran.  Perhaps its your version of jQuery ui?

Comment: @Trevor, is it possible to add class li in ul

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda I recommend creating a new question for that so that you can explain in depth what you are after.

Answer (score 31):

Modify the function like this to check for length of data.

```
success: function (data) {
    if(!data.length){
        var result = [
            {
                label: 'No matches found', 
                value: response.term
            }
        ];
        response(result);
    }
    else{
        // normal response
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.CompanyName + " (" + item.SymbolName + ")",
                value: item.CompanyName
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: But user can able to select `No matches found` and that is wrong, I don't understand why people do these types of workarounds.

Comment: That is easy to fix in select (events, ui) function.

Answer (score 11):

My answer is almost identical to @neelmeg and @Trever, but I have added an extra check, so user won't be able to select the "no result" message:

```
$(".my-textbox").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    open: function () { $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 50); },
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/some-url",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { prefix: request.term, __RequestVerificationToken: token },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.length) {
                    var result = [{ label: "no results", value: response.term }];
                    response(result);
                }
                else {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.someLabel, value: item.someValue };
                    }))
                }
            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var label = ui.item.label;
            if (label === "no results") {
            // this prevents "no results" from being selected
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            /* do something with the selected result */
            var url = "some-url"
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason, why this messages occured were:

```
MISSING CSS FILES O JQUERY UI
```

so adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/themes/flick/jquery.ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

solved my problem