# How to display "No results" text in devbridge's Ajax autocomplete jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using [devbridge's Ajax autocomplete jQuery plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) to get search suggestions.

I am trying to show "No Results" text when there is no suggestion.
I have searched a lot on StackOverflow. Most of the answers suggested adding parameters of **showNoSuggestionNotice: true** and **noSuggestionNotice: "No results found."**

However, it still doesn't work for me.

I also read the answer of [jQuery UI autocomplete- no results message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053231/jquery-ui-autocomplete-no-results-message/23762395#23762395) but I think it's referring to a different jQuery UI autocomplete widget because its parameters are different from the one I am using.

Code:

```
$(function(){
$('#search_key').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: WORK_ROOT+'index.php?page_key=display_search_result&mode=get_suggestions',
    paramName:'search_key',
    onSearchStart: function(q) {
                $('#search_key').autocomplete('hide');
    },
    noCache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        //arm : submit search
        searchProducts()
    },
    onHint: function (hint) {
        $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
    },
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    noSuggestionNotice: "No results found."
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23762395/1793718

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI autocomplete- no results message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053231/jquery-ui-autocomplete-no-results-message)

Comment: I have read this answer but I didn't able to get any help from it. Because here, I am not using any success or response parameters.

Comment: You are not using jQuery UI autocomplete plugin. Please remove it from the tags. You are using devbridge's  Ajax autocomplete jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it was on the backend. Needed to arrange the suggestions array in proper form.

Example:

```
$reply['suggestions'] = array();
if($result_records)
{
    $result_records = array_unique($result_records);
    foreach($result_records as $result_record)
    {
        $reply['suggestions'][] = array('value' => $result_record, 'data' => $result_record);
    }
}
echo json_encode($reply);exit;
```